# ¿Cual seria el equivalente de cout y cin de c++ en nodejs?

Tags: nodejs

Estaba realizando ejercicios de la universidad en C++ y en paralelo los estaba desarrollando en nodejs, pero estoy atascado en este problema, por ejemplo éste código en C++

```
int main(){

string Nombre;

cout << "Saludos compañero, introduce tu nomnbre:" << endl;

cin >> Nombre;

cout << "Hola " << Nombre << " Bienvenido al programa" << endl;

cout << "::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::" << endl;



return 0;
```

}

el detalle es que no conozco los métodos equivalentes de **cin** y **cout** en node, por lo que se me dificulta pasar dicho código, la idea era hacer lo mismo que se expone arriba pero con nodejs.

Comment: [`cin`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_stdin), [`cout`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para cout es `process.stdout.write("hola\n")` o `console.log("hola")`
para cin tenes que usar el módulo `readline` dipsonible y documentado en el core de `nodejs`